# Running executable on a server with user interaction

Tags: php, web-services, apache

I am looking for a way to run an executable on the server and display its UI in the browser, so that the user can interact. Is it possible? If so, please suggest some ways of how I should do this.

I think that this will have something to do with Flash, Flex, ActiveX (choose which applicable), but I am not sure and that is why I am actually asking this question.

Before you ask, "What do I need this for?", I would like to create a simple Intranet website for my local network so that my relatives can use few applications from their browsers instead of network shares or remote desktop connections.

The website will be done in PHP and running on Apache.

Any ideas, people?

Comment: what kind of applications/executables are we talking about?

Comment: Windows x86 executables (written in Delphi).

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult because you cannot magically transform the UI of those applications to a UI that would render in a browser. Also, your Delphi applications likely dont have any entry points for handling HTTP based requests. Even if you could provide those via PHP you'd still have to delegate them to the executable then somehow, which means your Delphi app needs to provide the full functionality via a command line interface or similar means.

**EDIT** came across https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AO-qca9ddqg. The video shows how to run applications built with a GTK3 UI, like GIMP, in the browser. The application itself is run and maintained completely on the server. [PHP does have bindings for GTK](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=php%20gtk&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://gtk.php.net/&ei=tjGpTtH2PI-JhQfV2-l2&usg=AFQjCNE4XdBoZ0E1sPv5ZKik8eCg-zk3zA&cad=rja) though not for GTK3, so while it's not currently possible, it is in theory.

Comment: True, there's a library for that called UniGUI for Delphi which adds the functionality you are talking about, but what about other applications? Isn't there a chance to display an application in some kind of an ActiveX control?

Comment: @Pateman I'm not aware of anything like that, which doesnt mean much, but I'd be really suprised if something like this exists. I'll happily delete my answer if you can get that work.

Comment: I just had an idea. I'll keep you notified.

Comment: Gordon, how do I contact you? Please send me a mail, it should be visible on my profile here at StackOverflow.

Comment: @Pateman there is a contact form on my website (mentioned on my Twitter page). Hint: I cannot answer if you dont put your email address into it ;)

Comment: Check if you received the form. :)

Comment: @Pateman check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AO-qca9ddqg&feature=player_embedded. It might be possible when you are using GTK.

Comment: Looks promising. My idea is to create something like that for ANY application. But I take my hat off - it really looks like great work!